# Subclassing DecimalField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, subclassing

I'm trying to create a `DecimalField` subclass, using the code below

```
class PositiveMoneyField(DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self,
            verbose_name, name,
            max_digits=9, decimal_places=2,
            validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal(0.0)), ],
            **kwargs
    )
```

But it give me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'max_digits'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking other django fields as [SlugField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2055), I found the solution:

```
class PositiveMoneyField(DecimalField):

    def __init__(self, *args, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'validators': [MinValueValidator(Decimal(0.01)), ]})
        super().__init__(*args, max_digits=max_digits, decimal_places=decimal_places, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **init** in DecimalField expects different call. Try this:

```
class PositiveMoneyField(DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(
            {'validators': [MinValueValidator(Decimal(0.0)), ]})
        super(PositiveMoneyField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @Eric-acevedo try now, and also look at the source code in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1427